# Any difference between two ways of declaring an event on a React component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What is the difference between these two ways of declaring that a React component has an event? Is it just a matter of style, or are the some other - even subtle - differences between the two?

```js
interface PropsA {
  onClick: () => void;
}

const ButtonA = (props: PropsA) => {
  // ...
}


interface PropsB {
  onClick(): void;
}

const ButtonB = (props: PropsB) => {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of style, please refer to official docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/cheatsheets, more specifically "Common syntax" section of the "interfaces" cheatsheet.